# Visual Studio Macro to Indent C/C++ Braces

Tags: visual-studio, macros, indentation

We have an old project that we maintain that uses brace indenting.  Rather than having to change my Visual Studio options every time I switch projects, I'd like to be able to do this quickly and easily.

I'm trying to write a macro in Visual Studio to turn Brace Indenting on and off.

The checkbox is under Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting

Indentation: Indent Braces

This doesn't work:

```
DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "C/C++").Item("IndentBraces").Value = True
```

I get "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Any ideas?  I haven't been able to find anything on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following is the correct macro code to make this work

```
DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "C/C++ Specific").Item("IndentBraces").Value = True
```

see: "[Determining Names of Property Items in Tools Options Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165642(VS.80).aspx)"  which is only mildly helpful in this situation but gave me enough of a clue to find it.